# Having trouble accessing virtual collection from cshtml razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, ef-core-2.1

I have a class which has a collection of the activity lines of the heder which is a one to many linked by activitylines id.

```
public class ActivityHeader
{ 
    public int ActivityHeaderId { get; set; } //(int, null)
    public DateTime? ActivityDate { get; set; } //(date, null)
    public string Name { get; set; } //(nvarchar(350), null)
    public DateTime? ActivityEndDate { get; set; } //(datetime, null)
    public string ProblemDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } //(nvarchar(max), null)

    public int? ActivityLinesId { get; set; } //(int, null)
    public int? HoursLeftOnProject { get; set; } //(time(7), null)
    public int? Status { get; set; } //(nchar(10), null)
      public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; } //(date, null)
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } //(nvarchar(50), null)
    public bool? isActive { get; set; } //(bit, null)
    public bool? isDeleted { get; set; } //(bit, null)
    public bool? isArchived { get; set; } //(bit, null)
    public int? SOP { get; set; } //(nvarchar(50), null)
    public int? OnSite { get; set; }
    public int? Remote { get; set; }

    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; } //(int, null)
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; } //(nvarchar(301), null)
    [ForeignKey("StaffId")]
    public int? StaffId { get; set; }
    public  virtual StaffMembers StaffMembers { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ActivityLines> ActivityLines { get; set; }


}
```

Activity Lines classs

```
public class ActivityLines
  {
        [Key]
        public int ActivityLineId { get; set; } //(int, not null)
        public int ActivitiyHeadId { get; set; } //(int, null)
        public string Description { get; set; } //(nvarchar(max), null)
        public string Notes { get; set; } //(nvarchar(max), null)
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; } //(time(7), null)
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; } //(time(7), null)
        public int? StaffMemeber { get; set; } //(int, null)
        public bool? isActive { get; set; } //(bit, null)
        public bool? isDeleted { get; set; } //(bit, null)
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; } //(nvarchar(50), null)
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; } //(date, null)
        public int? Status { get; set; } //(int, null)

  }
```

However as you see it not allowing me to link without going to the first record using linq what is the best practise in being able to reference the lines correclty.

```
@model ActivityTrackerDal.ViewModels.ActivityEditViewModal


<div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <label for="inputFirstname">Activty Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstname" placeholder="Activity name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">Activity Start Date</label>
                        @Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.ActivityDate)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">Activity End Date</label>
                        @Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.ActivityEndDate)
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">Location</label>
                        @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.Location)
                        {
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.OnSite, item.Value, false)
                            <label class="control-label">@item.Text</label>
                        }
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">Description</label>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "whatever-class", @cols = 115, @rows = 10 })

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="inputCity">Status </label>
                        <select asp-for="Status"
                                class="form-control"
                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ProjectStatusTypes,"LookupCode", "LookupDescription"))"></select>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="inputState">ActivityType </label>
                        <select asp-for="ActivityType"
                                class="form-control"
                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ProjectTypes,"LookupCode", "LookupDescription"))"></select>


                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="inputCity">Staff </label>
                        <select asp-for="StaffID"
                                class="form-control"
                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListOfStaff,"StaffID", "FirstName"))"></select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="inputState">Hours Left On Project </label>
                        <label for="inputState"><div class="badge" style="font-size:18px;">26</div> </label>
                        <label for="projecthours">If Porject hours fall below ten Contact Charlie.</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">

                    <div class="col-sm-12">

                        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<FuelActivityTrackerDal.Models.ActivityLines>().Name("activityLines")

                                                .Columns(columns =>
                                                {
                                                    columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Filterable(false);
                                                    columns.Bound(p => p.StartTime).Filterable(false);
                                                    columns.Bound(p => p.EndTime).Filterable(false);
                                                    columns.Bound(p => p.Status);
                                                    columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewDetails").Click("showDetails"));

                                                })
                                                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                    .Ajax()
                                                    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                                                   .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ActivityLineId))
                                                   .Read(read => read.Action("ActivityLines_Read", "Activity"))))
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                    </div>
                </div>


                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4 float-right">Add Work Item</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4 float-right">Put Case & Client On Hold</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Cancel</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Details")
                    .Title("Activity Details")
                    .Visible(false)
                    .Modal(true)
                    .Draggable(true)
                    .Width(400)
    )
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
        <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("SaveWorkItem", "Activity")">

            <div id="details-container">

                ActivitiyHeadId
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <label for="inputFirstname">Activty Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstname" placeholder="Activity name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">Description</label>
                        @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.ActivityLines.First(), new { @class = "whatever-class", @cols = 115, @rows = 10 })

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">Start Time</label>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">End Time </label>


                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-file px-4" value="Save Work Item" />


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Cancel</button>

        </form>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

        function showDetails(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
            var wnd = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");

            wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
            wnd.center().open();
        }
    </script>


</div>
```

Its this popup within  I am having the issue with being able to reference the  the activity lines

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
        <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("SaveWorkItem", "Activity")">

            <div id="details-container">

                ActivitiyHeadId
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <label for="inputFirstname">Activty Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstname" placeholder="Activity name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">Description</label>
                        @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.ActivityLines.First(), new { @class = "whatever-class", @cols = 115, @rows = 10 })

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">Start Time</label>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">End Time </label>


                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-file px-4" value="Save Work Item" />


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Cancel</button>

        </form>
    </script>
```

This is the main block from above I am having the issue with.

```
<div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <label for="inputLastname" class="form-control">Description</label>
                        @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.ActivityLines.First(), new { @class = "whatever-class", @cols = 115, @rows = 10 })

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Do I need to use include here on the ActivityHeader get statement like I have done for the staff?.

```
public List<ActivityEditViewModal> GetAllActivites()
    {
        var staffRepo = new StaffRepositry(_db);

        List<ActivityHeader> activity = new List<ActivityHeader>();
        activity = _db.ActivityHeader.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.StaffMembers)
            .ToList();

        if (activity != null)
        {
            List<ActivityEditViewModal> activityDisplay = new List<ActivityEditViewModal>();
            foreach (var x in activity)
            {
                var customerDisplay = new ActivityEditViewModal()
                {

                    ActivityHeaderId = x.ActivityHeaderId,
                    ActivityDate = x.ActivityDate,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    ActivityEndDate = x.ActivityEndDate,
                    Description = x.Description



                };
                activityDisplay.Add(customerDisplay);
            }
            return activityDisplay;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok So this is what I had to do I had to use the function called include which is explained in this article on Microsoft web site. Its called defered loading and by the reason of this is EF6 used to take forever to load one to many relationships actually a problem i had with an old app as EF6 uses lazy loading which always loaded all one to many relationships now you can load them when you require them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

```
public List<ActivityEditViewModal> GetAllActivites()
{
    var staffRepo = new StaffRepositry(_db);

    List<ActivityHeader> activity = new List<ActivityHeader>();
    activity = _db.ActivityHeader.AsNoTracking()
       .Include(x => x.StaffMembers)
       .Include(x=>x.ActivityLines)
       .ToList();

    if (activity != null)
     {
         List<ActivityEditViewModal> activityDisplay = new 
           List<ActivityEditViewModal>();
           foreach (var x in activity)
           {
              var customerDisplay = new ActivityEditViewModal()
               {
                  ActivityHeaderId = x.ActivityHeaderId,
                  ActivityDate = x.ActivityDate,
                  Name = x.Name,
                  ActivityEndDate = x.ActivityEndDate,
                  Description = x.Description,
                  ActivityLines = x.ActivityLines
              };
                  activityDisplay.Add(customerDisplay);
             }
           return activityDisplay;          
}
```